# Can you make a faraday cage intended to effect electrical wires?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, signal-processing

Generally with a faraday cage your object is completely surrounded and encapsulated within the cage. Let's say I have a wire with electronic signals flowing through it, say an ethernet cable that is too long to encapsulate. Does there still exists some method to disable this wire or render it unusable from scrambling?

I believe there could some configuration of magnetics or modification of a faraday cage that could accomplish this but I am not sure what to search up or how to find this information.

Comment: That's called a coaxial cable. In case of ethernet we use twisted pairs and differential signals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_pair.

Comment: After reading about coax cables I understand why you shared it. My question was more intended to find out how I could create a contraption that effects wires externally. I get that inside coax cables are "mini faraday cages" but how can I effect a pre-existing electrical coax cable. For example could I bring electromagnets to a portion of the coax cables and cause disturbances? @FlatterMann

Comment: A back hoe has been shown to work nicely for this job.

Comment: Something that does not cause permanent damage. @ThePhoton